# Authorization fails in CMS textolite

Tags: javascript, html, css, content-management-system

Good day.
Recently I installed the admin panel textolite. Everything worked well. Now I decided to check, went through the url to textolite, entered the password. The textolite itself, after entering the password, writes that everything is ok, but then nothing happens, it does not transfer it to the admin panel itself. Maybe someone faced such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved a problem.
The site was on MAMP and had a title in two words (example-main). MAMP itself changed the sign "-" to "% 20" or something like that when going to the site. Removing the "-" sign it all worked